# How can I set the origin of a component I'm trying to make into a JLabel from top-left to bottom-left?

Tags: java, swing, sprite, jlabel

I'm trying to make a 2D sprite game, and as of now, the JLabel on which the image draws starts at the top left. This presents a problem when I try to move the sprite laterally because if the sprite that's supposed to come next is taller than the previous, it won't be standing on the floor as it should. In this picture, the left is the starting, the middle is what it does now with the top-left as 0,0, and the right is what it should be, screen-grabbed from the actual game.

below is my paint for the model of Mario:

```
  public void paint(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.drawImage(sprite, 0,0, null); 
  }
```

and below is my paintComponent that's in a class that when run, renders the image onto the screen:

```
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    marioSprite.paint(g2);
  }
```

and how I extract an image from a file:

```
 //generate URL
  public static URL urlGenerator(String name){
    URL u = lookup().lookupClass().getResource(name);
    return u;
  }

  //return image with filtered color
  public static BufferedImage generateAndFilter(BufferedImage b, URL u){

    try{
      b = ImageIO.read(u);
      int width = b.getWidth();
      int height = b.getHeight();
      int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
      b.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, pixels, 0, width); 
      for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {

        if (pixels[i] == 0xFFff00fe) {
          pixels[i] = 0x00ff00fe; 
        }
      }
      BufferedImage newSprite = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      newSprite.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, pixels, 0, width);
      b = newSprite;
    } 
    catch(IOException e){
      System.out.println("sprite not found");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return b;
  }
```

each instance of Mario has a sprite set by:

```
  public void setSprite(String spriteName){
    URL spriteAtLoc = Utils.urlGenerator(spriteName);
    this.sprite = Utils.generateAndFilter(sprite,spriteAtLoc);
    this.currentSpriteName = spriteName;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate more?

Comment: the top-left of Mario's head is still at the same y-coordinate in the second image, but since the second sprite is taller, one pixel down is cut off. the third sprite is what it should be.

Comment: Can you just draw the second image one pixel up?

Comment: How do you draw your animation? post the code.

Comment: other than the paint and paintComponent methods, what do you need? You need how I get the .bmp files onto the screen?

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki any ideas?